# Disable TabBar for specific Tab when keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-tabactivity

I need to disable showing the tab bar above keyboard when its up for only specific tab.
I've searched and tried several ways:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"` works but for all tabs. I need only for one tab

- The only way i think should work is to send broadcast from the tab fragment to the TabActivity, it works fine but when dealing (typing/deleting) with the only edit text in the fragment something goes wrong in the tab bar goes up with the keyboard again.

The broadcast is: (Tab fragment):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TabActivityName.ACTION_SET_SOFT_INPUT_MODE);
    intent.putExtra(TabActivityName.SOFT_INPUT_MODE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And from the TabActivityName the broadcast is being called successfully and do:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(intent.getIntExtra(SOFT_INPUT_MODE, 0));
```

So my main issue is what can cause the tab activity to disable/reset/forget this softInputMode

thank for the help